# Debugging in pydev - how to make python objects expandable - as in java debugger?

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev, expandable

Especially standard types like dictionaries and lists - e.g. imagine you have dictionary of dictionaries of lists - then when you go over some variable (in debug) - the debugger will show it as static object.toString() representation instead of expandable (clickable) java or c++ debugger representations. This feature seems to me pretty essential is there a way how to enable it in PyDev - or is there some other IDE with whatever plugins that has this feature ?

Answer (score 1):

In PyDev **Variables view supports** expandable objects. Expressions View doesn't.

There is already feature request for this
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2947729&group_id=85796&atid=577332

Comment: What I actually meant is that I would like it to display quick view - when you move mouse over the variable in code (or quick inspect) without necesity to use expression window

Answer (score 1):

Grab the latest release (PyDev 2.2.4) where this should be fixed.

Also, it might be worth nothing that in PyDev, the console may be used to gather information on objects in a debug session ( see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html )